# How to implement fullscreen using execcommand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, execcommand

I need to make my text editor full screen. How can I implement this using `execcommand`?
I don't know if it is possible with `execcommand` or if I need jQuery or JavaScript for this, I don't need the <kbd>F11</kbd> functionality, please help me?

Answer (score 0):

**[CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)** has an inbuilt option to view the editor as full screen.

Comment: I am trying to building a new text editor, so that i need this functionality

Comment: Hope you can use jquery to maximise the editor area to the full width and height of the screen.